# Unbound copy service for Android

Tags: java, android, service, nullpointerexception, android-service

Ok, so I'm working on an Android program that will list the things you copied in history. I used to have an activity do this, but I want it to work even when the activity is not running in the background, so I'm working on a service to get the data that the user copies, and call an activity method for it to be processed and listed in the app. Here is my service:

public class Operation extends Service {

```
private static int NOTIFY_ID = 1;
ClipData.Item item;
String newText;
ClipboardManager clipboard;
Context context = this;
ArrayList<String> operationVals = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder tasker =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon)
                    .setContentTitle("Copy Data Recorder")
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentText("Recording copied data");


    Intent copyAction = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendAction = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, copyAction, 0);

    tasker.setContentIntent(pendAction);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, tasker.build());

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


     clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() { 


        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {

            ClipData clip = clipboard.getPrimaryClip(); 

            try {

                item = clip.getItemAt(0);

            } catch (Exception e) {


            }

            newText = item.coerceToText(context).toString();
            operationVals.add(newText);

            try { 


                MainActivity messager = new MainActivity();

                messager.doIt(operationVals); 

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Exception Error: " + e);
            }


        }

    });

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

Basically, every time, it's getting what is copied, adding it to a String array list "operationVals", and calling the method doIt() of the main activity. doIt() loops through the array, checks to see which copied data is new, and adds it to a array list of EditText objects named "ets" which are displayed when the app activity is opened. Here it is:

public void doIt(ArrayList values) {

```
    for (String element : values) {

        if (ets.size() != 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < ets.size(); i++) {

                String element2 = ets.get(i).getText().toString();

                if (element2.equals(element)) {

                    values.remove(i);

                }
            }
        }

    }

    if (values.size() != 0) {

        for (String newText : values) {


            /* If the size is zero and we currently have no items, this one should
               be immediately added.*/

            if (ets.size() == 0) {

                ets.add(new EditText(context)); //Adds EditText field
                ets.get(ets.size() - 1).setText(newText); //Sets newText string in EditText that was created
                linearlayout.addView(ets.get(ets.size() - 1)); //Adds element to view
                contentSpace.add(ets.get(ets.size() - 1).getText().toString());

            } else if (ets.size() != 0) {

                oldText = ets.get(ets.size() - 1).getText().toString();

                // Checks that new copied data is different from previous data and does not contain only spaces
                if (!newText.equals(oldText) && newText.trim().length() > 0 && oldText.trim().length() > 0) {

                    ets.add(new EditText(context)); //Adds EditText field
                    ets.get(ets.size() - 1).setText(newText); //Sets newText string in EditText that was created
                    linearlayout.addView(ets.get(ets.size() - 1)); //Adds element to view
                    contentSpace.add(ets.get(ets.size() - 1).getText().toString());

                } else if (oldText.trim().length() == 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < ets.size(); i++) {

                        if (ets.get(i).getText().toString().equals(oldText)) {

                            oldText = oldText.trim();
                            ets.get(ets.size() - 1).setText(newText);

                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

However, I test it out, and things seem to be going just fine until doIt() is called by my service and the program starts working on checking ets and adding the elements to it, and I get a NullPointerException. It seems that ets has been properly declared and initialized and my activity has obviously been created (the service is started in onStart() of the main activity). I would appreciate if anyone can please help me out with this to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems in your code:

- you can not instantiate an Activity like this: MainActivity messager = new MainActivity();
  activities can be started (or activated) only by using Intents (Intent.startActivity family of methods).
- You should either use a BroadcastReceiver or a Messenger to handle the communication between the Service and the Activity.
- consider scenarios like when you send data to the activity but the activity is in background and in a stopped state (Activity.onPause and Activity.onStop will be called when an Activity is in background). In this case you can call Intent.startActivity again but with the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) set, this will cause the activity to be brought in the foreground (will not recreate a new instance of the activity if one already exists)
- consider moving the logic that you have set up in Service.onStartCommand to Service.onCreate, as Service.onStartCommand will be called each time you call Context.startService method and each time will override the previous settings.